# How would I pick a random character from a string/array with Bash?

Tags: bash, random

I have an example where I am attempting to randomly generate a letter in a set of letters (i.e. var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").

**How would I have:**

```
var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

echo "${var}"
```

**yield:** *`some_letter`*

The point is, I’m trying to automatically generate a **random letter** from a **selection of my choosing**. Whether it be in an array or a string does not matter.

Comment: Arrays and strings are two different datatypes

Comment: Which shell, by the way? You also tagged this for `sh`, but if you need sh compatibility, some bash-only techniques aren't available.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: What do you mean, "variable arrays"? This **isn't an array at all**. And if you're working in bash, why did you roll back my edit removing the `sh` tag?

Comment: (Similarly, the `terminal` tag is only for questions about terminals -- which this isn't -- and the `linux` tag is for questions that are specific to Linux, which this *likewise* isn't).

Comment: Changed the title to match OP's ask.

Comment: @codeforester, ...I did that myself, earlier, and the OP [rolled it back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48837407/revisions).

Comment: I apologize. I don’t know how Stack Exchange works, so I assumed it was some kind of mistake and changed it.

Comment: This was so long ago, I'd entirely forgotten about this; thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
echo "${var:$(( RANDOM % ${#var} )):1}" # pick a 1 char substring starting at a random position
```

This works because:

- `${var:START:LEN}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) that expands to a substing of `$var`
- `${#var}` is a parameter expansion that expands to the length of the contents of the string variable var
- `$(( ))` creates an arithmetic context, in which context non-numeric strings are assumed to refer to variable names (so one can use `RANDOM` instead of `$RANDOM`).
- `$RANDOM`, each time it is evaluated, expands to a random integer between 0 and 32767.
- `$RANDOM % ${#var}` takes the remainder of dividing that random integer by the number of characters in the string named `var`; consequently, it will be between 0 and (length-of-`var` - 1), and will be *almost* randomly divided (if the length-of-`var` doesn't divide into 32768 evenly, then some of the characters will have a very slightly higher chance of being chosen than others).

Thus, `${var:$(( RANDOM % ${#var} )) : 1}` will, each time it is evaluated, pick a location inside the string, and expand to a single-character span within it.

Answer (score 8):

For most practical cases, the solution of [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837435/8344060) is the way forward. However, if your random character picking has to be uniform, then the story becomes slightly more complicated when you want to use `RANDOM` (see explanation below). The best way forward would be the usage of `shuf`. `shuf` generates a random permutation of a given range and allows you to pick the first number like `shuf -i 0-25 -n1`, so you could use

```
var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
echo ${var:$(shuf -i 0-$((${#var}-1)) -n1):1}
```

The idea here is to pick a letter from the string `var` by using the pattern expansion `${var:m,n}` where you pick a substring starting at `m` of length `n`.  The length is set to `1` and the starting position is defined by the command `shuf -i 0-$((${#var}-1)` which shuffles a range between 0 and `${#var}-1` where `${#var}` is the string length of the variable `var`.

---

**Why not using `RANDOM`:**

The random variable `RANDOM` generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 32767. This implies that if you want to generate a random number between `0` and `n`, you cannot use the mod. The problem here is that the first `32768%n` numbers will have a higher chance to be drawn. This is easily seen with the following script :

```
% for i in {0..32767}; do echo $((i%5)); done | sort -g | uniq -c
   6554 0
   6554 1
   6554 2
   6553 3  < smaller change to hit 3
   6553 4  < smaller chance to hit 4
```

Another classic approach is to map the range of the random number generator onto the requested range by scaling the random value as `n*RANDOM/32768`. Unfortunately, this only works for a random number generator that generate real numbers. `RANDOM` generates an integer. The integer scaling essentially shuffles the earlier problem:

```
% for i in {0..32767}; do echo $((5*i/32768)); done | sort -g | uniq -c
   6554 0
   6554 1
   6553 2  < smaller chance to hit 2
   6554 3
   6553 4  < smaller chance to hit 4
```

If you want to use `RANDOM`, the best way is to skip the values which are not needed, this you can do with a simple `while` loop

```
var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
n=${#var}
idx=32769; while (( idx >= (32768/n)*n )); do idx=$RANDOM; done
char=${var:$idx:1}
```

**note:** it is possible that you are stuck for an eternity in the while loop.

**Comment:** we do not comment on how good the random number generator behind `RANDOM` is. All we do is cite the comment in the source :

> **source bash 4.4.18 (`variables.c`)**
>
> ```c
> /* A linear congruential random number generator based on the example
>    one in the ANSI C standard. This one isn't very good, but a more
>    complicated one is overkill.
> */
> ```

Comment: Good call. Definitely appropriate to be cautious if one were to be using this mechanism for cryptographic keys or such.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `shuf` in a maybe more concise way.

Basically you split the string into a char on each line and then use `shuf` the normal way:

*Using `fold` for splitting*

```sh
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | fold -w1 | shuf -n1
```

*Using `grep` for splitting*

```sh
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | grep -o . | shuf -n1
```

Comment: Nice 1 liner, if you find a way to make it shorter let me know. Thank You!